# Password Ubuntu 22.04 for Xilinx Devices

Tags: login, password, u-boot

I downloaded image and write it into SDcard refering to https://ubuntu.com/download/amd#community
and
https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/2363129857/Getting+Started+with+Certified+Ubuntu+22.04+LTS+for+Xilinx+Devices

it describes ID and password is ubuntu but I cannot login with it.
Is it updated? or am I misunderstading it?
Please guide me how to login ubuntu 22.04 LTS for Xilinx Devices
Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.